# AngularJS: How to add and compile a directive to the dom, from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think what I am trying to do is fairly simple, but I can't seem to determine the correct architecture using Angular.

I'd like to have a MessageCenter, so that any controller or other piece of Angular code can add a message. I thought that the correct way to do this would be with a MessageCenter service. I would inject the service where needed, and call MessageCenter.add(). The problem that I am having is how to compile the cloned DOM directive, since $compile requires a $scope, which I do not have from a service.

Here is what I am trying. I am not sure what the correct approach is for this.

```
<div>
  <div id="msg-proto" message-center-msg class="alert alert-success"></div>
</div>
```

Then:

```
.factory('MessageCenter', function($compile) {
  var that = {}

  that.add = function(type, message) {
    var n = $("#msg-proto"),
        n2 =  n.clone();
    n.parent().append($compile(n2));
  }

  return that;
});
```

And I am injecting and calling the service:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function(MessageCenter) {
  MessageCenter.add('some msg');
});
```

I have a `message-center-msg` directive defined that adds some behaviors to the element. But it needs to be `$compile`'d in order for that to happen, and I am not sure how to make this all work. I only ever end up with **"Error: Argument 'scope' is required"** from the service.

How can I setup a global message center, that is able to clone/add messages and have the directive on the message dom element processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service shouldn't interact with the DOM directly as you're trying to do. If I were designing such a system I would:

1. Have a service which simply takes in messages and either puts them in an array (if you want to support a whole list of messages) or simply remembers the last message (if you only want to support a single message)
2. Have a controller which gets the message service injected to it and binds the message(s) from the service into its scope
3. Then have a bit of HTML (or a custom directive) that iterates the messages using the above controller and displays them

Here's what I mean (plunk here: http://plnkr.co/Eps1Gy)

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>  
    <script src="scripts/controllers/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/click.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/messageService.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="messagesApp">
    <h1>Messages</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MessagesCtrl"> 
      <ul  ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <li>{{message}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a ng-href="#" ng-controller="ClickCtrl" ng-click="addMessage()" >Add a new message!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

messageService.js:

```
function MessageService() {
    this.messages = [];
    this.add = function(msg) {
        this.messages.push(msg);
    }
}

angular.module('messagesApp')
    .service('messageService', MessageService);
```

messages.js:

```
angular.module('messagesApp')
  .controller('MessagesCtrl', function ($scope, messageService) {
    $scope.messages = messageService.messages;
  });
```

click.js:

```
angular.module('messagesApp')
  .controller('ClickCtrl', function ($scope, messageService) {
    var count = 0;

    $scope.addMessage = function() {
        messageService.add('Test message ' + count++);
    }
  });
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('messagesApp', [])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Like I said, you can replace the HTML for handling the messages with a custom directive if you want some complex interaction, but the important thing is that you don't try to muck with the view from your service. The service should interact only with a well-defined model.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? I tried, and I can't get this to work. I'm also not clear on how any of this would work without an $apply() somewhere in there. In click.js, you are pushing onto the MessageService array, but how will the binding in MessagesCtrl be informed of this?

Comment: The reason adding to the array is instantly reflected in the UI is THE magic of angular.js. It automatically watches things bound into your scope and anything that depends on them is updated instantly. The example could also be better encapsulated by the messageService exposing a getMesages() rather than exposing the array of messages directly.

Comment: I cannot believe that this worked like this. Before, I was updating a scope property from a directive, and I had to wrap the update in an $apply() call. Now I'm not sure why that didn't work, but this did. For example, this was in the postLink function of the directive: `scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.data.hasOption = true;
        });` But without the $apply wrapper, Angular wasn't seeing the change, and an ng-class expression in the HTML wasn't updating accordingly. But why didn't you need $apply()? I am pretty confused on this now.

Comment: To quote the O'Reilly Angular.js book: "DO NOT call it [scope.$apply] all the time. DO call it when controls outside AngularJS (DOM events, jQuery UI controls, etc.) are calling AngularJS functions". Since my code handles clicks, etc. the "Angular way" there's no need to call scope.$apply.

Comment: OKay, so here's the full snippet. Maybe this is why I needed $apply(), since I was using an event handler that is technically outside of Angular (right?):       `ele.find("#myEle").on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.data.hasOption = true; 
        });
      });`  Okay, so what if you weren't using the click example? I want one controller to be able to post a message to the MessageCenter, and then still have everything else that you demonstrated happen. I guess that's what I was originally asking. So no ng-click involved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38293/discussion-between-vcardillo-and-ksimons)

Answer (score 2):

I implemented something pretty identical a while back and recently made this public as a bower component.
Maybe you can use or work off of it: https://github.com/IanShoe/angular-message-center

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can open your mind :)

On your call to the MessageCenter move the $scope as parameter like MessageCenter.add("", $scope);

Or ... you can expose the MessageCenter to the scope globally on startup something [like this guy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968373/how-do-i-expose-scope-in-an-angularjs-service)

Comment: The $scope that the MessageCenter needs is not the $scope of the caller. Any controller with any $scope may inject and invoke MessageCenter.add(). The $scope in any of those contexts is of the caller. However, the MessageCenter needs scope into where it should finally place the new message. This is unrelated to the caller.